# How i can remove libreries dependences?

Tags: dependencies

I make a dll with Visual Studio 2008, but it already depend of *msvcr90.dll* and *msvcp90.dll*, and for this reason my application don't work if Visual Studio 2008 isn't instaled. How I can do to remove those dependencies?

Comment: decompile...change dependencies and recompile

Comment: ok, I don't set the dependencies, was Visual Studio set the dependencies by itself

Comment: that's why I said recompile with the new VS

Comment: I'm trying not recompile the project, because is a really old big project with several dependencies to OpenCV and OpenCL, but I'm think that I actually have to do it; for that reason I'm looking for other solution, but apparently it must to be done, anyway thanks Steve, I will follow your advice.